# Github Actions to Google Functions 2nd gen

Tags: google-cloud-functions, github-actions

I am using Github Action in order to deploy Google Functions. How can I use the second generation, instead of the first generation?

This is my code:

**.github/workflows/google-cloud-function.yaml**

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions
name: CD

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: "read"
      id-token: "write"
    steps:
      - name: checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - id: "auth"
        name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: "projects/12345/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gh-pool/providers/gh-provider"
          service_account: "github-actions-service-account@PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      - id: "deploy"
        uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v0"
        with:
          name: "myapp"
          runtime: "python310"
          region: "europe-west1"
          entry_point: "main"
          timeout: 540
          service_account_email: PROJECT@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
          ingress_settings: ALLOW_ALL
          max_instances: 1

      # Example of using the output
      - id: "test"
        run: 'curl "${{ steps.deploy.outputs.url }}"'
```

**This is how I set it up to be deployed everytime I push changes to Github:**

*Powershell:*

```
$GITHUB_REPO="ORGANIZATION/{YOUR-REPO-NAME}"
$PROJECT_ID="PROJECT"
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT="github-actions-service-account"
$WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL="gh-pool"
$WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER="gh-provider"
```

*Project ID*

```
gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
```

*Get ID:*

```
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools describe $WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL --location="global" --format="value(name)"

--> projects/XXXX/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gh-pool

$WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID="projects/XXXX/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gh-pool"
```

*Connect repository:*

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding $SERVICE_ACCOUNT@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser" --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository/${GITHUB_REPO}"
```

Comment: .@Europa I have posted the answer as [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) so that others who are facing the similar issue could spot the workaround easier

Comment: This is now possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77337408/1759443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think currently it is not possible to deploy a 2nd Gen cloud function with a Github Action. There is already  request raised for this at [github](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/issues/304) which is mentioned like below.

> GitHub Actions only to deploy cloud function 1st gen. We do not
> currently support Cloud Functions gen2. If you need support for gen2,
> you can use the setup-gcloud action and run a `gcloud` command
> manually.

you may also add your concern in that github issue which is still open, you can follow that issue  for updates and further progress can be tracked there.

As community member mentioned the workaround in below comment  you can use this until the  feature is  available

> There is a [thread on pull request #357](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/pull/357) where another user has
> included their workaround [setup-gcloud job configuration](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/pull/357#issuecomment-1270506981).

Comment: Additionally there is a [thread on pull request #357](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/pull/357) where another user has included their [`setup-gcloud` job configuration](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/pull/357#issuecomment-1270506981).

Comment: The extra service account looks like the best method of solving the issue I have.

Comment: If the information in my answer was useful consider accepting or upvoting:) Feel free to ask further queries.

Answer (score 1):

Now, we can deploy the 2nd Gen cloud function through GitHub actions using gcloud cli.

Here is an Example:

```
name: build-and-deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy-production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
    - uses: 'actions/checkout@v3'
    - run: ls
    - id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}'

    - name: Debug GCP credentials
      env:
        GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}
      run: |
        echo "$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" > credentials.json

    - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1'
      with:
        version: '>= 363.0.0'
    - name: 'Use gcloud CLI'
      run: 'gcloud info' 
    - name: Install Python dependencies
      run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: 'Deploy a gen 2 cloud function'
      run: 'gcloud functions deploy test-function --gen2 --runtime=python310 --region=asia-south1 --trigger-http --entry-point=handle --memory=256MB --timeout=60s'
```